# Custom build for scdf throwing transaction manager conflicts

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to make custom build for spring cloud dataflow server.
Below is my pom.xml:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.2.7.RELEASE


com.example
custom-dataflow-server-maven
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
custom-dataflow-server
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-cloud-dataflow.version>2.5.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-dataflow.version>
    <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.3.7.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
    <mariadb.version>2.4.1</mariadb.version>
    <kubernetes-client.version>4.1.0</kubernetes-client.version>
    <nimbus-jose-jwt.version>8.17</nimbus-jose-jwt.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
        <version>${kubernetes-client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-dataflow.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-release</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

*****but it throws error below:*****

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 1 of method jobRepositoryFactoryBean in org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.config.features.TaskConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- transactionManager: defined by method 'transactionManager' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]
- springCloudTaskTransactionManager: defined by method 'springCloudTaskTransactionManager' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/configuration/SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration.class]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

1. Is it because I am missing any dependencies? How can I make one of the beans primary in this case? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides @Primary annotation which declares a specific bean as primary, which means primary bean will be given higher preferences when autowiring to a single-valued dependency.

On the other hand, Spring also provides @Qualifier annotation in which the specific bean name is mentioned in its argument. Based on the argument, a specific bean is selected. You should try these annotations.

For more reference - [click1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary) [click2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation)